# Bootstrap popover focus not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a rendered html using jQuery which includes onclick function:

```
$.each(response, function(index, item) {

    $('#appendTarget').append('<div class="col-md-3" style="border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 12px; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px;">' + item.name +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-3"><a class="btn" role="button" onclick="showPopover(this)"><b style="color: red">X</b></button>');

});
```

And after this I have implemented the `showPopover` function:

```
function showPopover(element) {
  $(element).popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'focus',
        content: function() {
            return $('#popover-content').html();
        }
  });
}
```

Like this it is not working. But if I remove this `trigger: 'focus'` it works.

Any idea why is it like so?

Comment: Cause you are saying that focus will trigger it...?

Comment: I want to close the popover when another "button" is clicked. That's why I use focus.

Comment: So why don't you just bind button click?

Comment: But I did. It is in `onclick` event.

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/) says 
***Specific markup required for dismiss-on-next-click
For proper cross-browser and cross-platform behavior, you must use the <*a*> tag, not the <*button*> tag, and you also must include a tabindex attribute.***

You will need to add a **tabindex** to your button, like so
    <*a class="btn" tabindex="0" role="button" onclick="showPopover(this)"*>

Answer (score 2):

The `focus trigger` doesn't work because the focus/tab is not applied to the anchor tag you are trying to trigger.

Try adding `tabindex="-1"` to the `Html` tag that is triggering the `popover`.